# На каком WiFi железе из простого можно (2 SSID в одном влане и метить для DHCP какой SSID)

Tags: wifi, vlan

То есть надо чтобы  клиенты подключающиеся к WiFi SSID сеть1 получали одни параметры DHCP,  а  клиенты из сеть2 - Другие. Оба SSID  надо делать одной ( одними) точками доступа. Не могу найти кто из дешевого оборудования умеет вешать из какого SSID поступил запрос для DHCP. Надо чтобы клиеты обоих SSID остались в одном L2 пространстве. И нужно чтобы из коробки ( не тот случай когда можно  повесить сервер с бриджом)... :(

Comment: Посмотрите эту ссылку например https://superuser.com/questions/373175/two-ssids-on-one-router

Answer (score 1):

**Вариант сложный**

Насчет железа не подскажу конкретно. Возьмите опенврт, например. Можно микротик.

Чтоб раздавать разные сети на разные ssid сетки всё же придется разделить на разные интерфейсы. На каждом из них запускается DHCP с разными подсетями и указываете маршрут в scope link для каждого беспроводного интерфейса, а также для присоединяемого к ним проводного. Потом надо включить proxy-arp на всех соединяемых интерфейсах. Так получится псевдобридж. Для работы мультикаста (рабочая группа или иптв) через него понадобится еще igmpproxy.

**Вариант проще**

Микротик не пойдет в качестве свича, но точки доступа любые с мультиссид.

Делаете вланы на каждый ссид, заводите точку доступа в управляемый свич с поддержкой dhcp option 82. Делаем аггрегацию на этом свиче - вводим оба влана в аксес на одном порту. Разбираете option 82 на выделенном дхчп сервере (isc dhcpd) и выдаете адреса в соответствии с вланом.

Comment: не отписался, но уже  решил  именно при помощи  82-й опции, причем  без  разных VLAN, есть точки  ( edimax  и eltex  точно ), которые  передают SSID  в  82-й опции. Далее  делаем два пула из  двух соседних сетей и расширяем маску, так чтобы была видимость между обоими диапазонами.

Comment: в дешевых точках доступа нет 82 опции к сожалениию..

Comment: ага, так вопрос  и был - в  ком подешевле  есть :) .  Вероятно очень плохо сформулировал